# Highcharts renders the other graph's data too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have one html page where there are two divs. In each div I am loading different jsp files(**one.jsp and two.jsp**).

**home.html:**

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/export-csv.js"></script> 
<script>
 function loadGraphs()
   {
    $('#plotContainer1').load('one.jsp');
    $('#plotContainer2').load('two.jsp');
   }
</script>
```

where `plotContainer1` and `plotContainer2` are two divs. So that I want to load two graphs at a time.

**one.jsp:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 350px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var seriesArray;
var chart;
callAjax();
var graphTitle = "";
var chart;

function drawgraph1() {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#54CBE5', '#57B442']
    });
    chart =  $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
             title: {
                text: graphTitle
         },
         xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 30,
            type: 'datetime',

               categories: xAxisCategories 
        },
        yAxis: {
            min : 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
        plotLines : [ {
            value : 0,
            width : 1,
            color : '#808080'
        } ]

       },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }, 
            series : seriesArray
    });

};

function callAjax() {
    $("#container1").empty();

         seriesArray = [{
                name: 'line1',
                data: []
            }, {
                name: 'line2',
                data: []
            }];
    xAxisCategories = [];

    var params = {"param1" : value};        
    $.getJSON("graph1datafetcher",params, function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                var xaxisPoints=data[key];
                xAxisCategories.push(Date.parse(key));
                for(var i in xaxisPoints) {
                    seriesArray[i].data.push(xaxisPoints[i]);  
                }
            });

            console.log(" JSON: " + JSON.stringify(data));

            drawgraph1();
        });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**two.jsp** almost contains the same code. Now first **two.jsp** loads as it contains less data compared to **one.jsp**. When **one.jsp** loads in and shows up in div, the **one.jsp** graph shows **two.jsp** data and its own data too. I am logging the data in the console, the data that is coming is fine. So, the problem is somewhere the highchart persists the first data. I have been struggling with this for past 7 hours. Can someone please answer how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are using exactly the same variables names, which are **global**. So one variables are overwriting second ones. Make variable local (by passing as arguments to functions), or change names.

Comment: xAxisCategories is global. Declare it with var at the top.